# Bootstrap 4 and Flex can not get this right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi all I am needing some help with something that should be pretty simple but I can not seem to get it right after a few hours of playing with it.

[image]

All I want is a 3 column layout with variable height images to always align bottom, and for the variable length text to always align top.

So far this is what I have but the h-100 class on the card is also taking the text height into account and then the bottom does not seem to know where it is, so the footer crashes over the text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container">

  <div class="row bg-dark">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1 class="text-light">Heading</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card border-0 h-100">
        <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-end px-0">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card border-0 h-100">
        <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-end px-0">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/360/640" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card border-0 h-100">
        <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-end px-0">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="row border-1">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="text-dark mb-0">Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `align-items-end` class to row. check out my solution in full page view.

```
  <div class="row align-items-end">
       <!-- content -->
  <div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row bg-dark">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1 class="text-light">Heading</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card border-0">
        <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-end px-0">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card border-0">
        <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-end px-0">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/360/640" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card border-0">
        <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-end px-0">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit... Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row border-1">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="text-dark mb-0">Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing that makes everything align bottom, I want the 3 images aligned to the bottom of each other, and the 3 text blocks aligned to the top. So it looks like there is a vertical center point and everything comes out from it, so variable height images above and variable length text from the center down.

Comment: Just looked a little more at your answer and if I adjust it ever so slightly to rather use `align-items-baseline` then it does exactly what I want, thanks so much for leading me in the right direction.